# Поиск вводимого названия по ключам словаря и вывод соответствующих значений

Tags: python

Только начала осваивать Python, потому не судите строго. Задача такая: имеется массив, в котором содержатся сведения о ноутбуках (производитель, цена, и т.д.) Разделитель полей - знак табуляции.

```
source_data = [
"71370204    Ноутбук HP 15-bw625ur    26 990    28 990    Ноутбук HP 15-bw625ur (AMD A9-9420 3GHz/15.6\"/1366х768/8Gb/500Gb/AMD Radeon 520/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10 Home)15-bw625ur    80XS210MRK",
"71346124    Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 320-15ABR    34 800    36 990    Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 320-15ABR(AMD A10-9620P 2.5GHz/15.6\"/1920x1080/6Gb/1Tb/AMD Radeon R530M 2Gb/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10)IdeaPad 320-15ABR    80XS000MRK",
"71366543    Ноутбук LENOVO 320-15IKBN    32 990    37 990    Intel Core I3-7100U 2400Mhz/15.6\"/1920x1080/6Gb/1Tb/DVD нет/nVidia GeForce G940MX/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win10    320-15IKBN    80XL003ARK",
"71122779    Ноутбук APPLE MacBook Air 11.6    45 990    48 990    Intel Core i5-5250U 1.6GHz/11.6\"/1366х768/4Gb/128Gb SSD/Intel HD Graphics 6000/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/MacOS    MacBook Air 11.6    MJVM2RU/A",
"71345404    Ноутбук APPLE MacBook Pro 13    80 000    89 990    Intel Core i5-7360U 2.3GHz/13.3\"/2560x1600/8Gb/128Gb SSD/Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/MacOS    MacBook Pro 13    MPXQ2RU/A",
"71366549    Ноутбук LENOVO 320-15AST    26 990    29 990    AMD A9-9420 3000Mhz/15.6\"/1366x768/8Gb/1Tb/AMD Radeon HD R520/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win10    320-15AST    80XV00C9RK",
"71370165    Ноутбук ASUS k501uw-dm039t    52 990    59 990    Intel Core i5-6200U 2.3GHz/15.6\"/1920х1080/8Gb/1Tb/NVIDIA GeForce GTX960M/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10    k501uw-dm039t    80YY0002RK",
"71371449    Ноутбук ACER Aspire A315-21-46X9    18 990    19 990    AMD A4-9120 2.2GHz/15.6\"/1366х768/4GB/500GB/AMD Radeon R3/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10 Home    Aspire A315-21-46X9    NX.GNVER.024",
"71371450    Ноутбук ACER Aspire ES1-533-P8HY    19 990    20 990    Intel Pentium N4200 1.1GHz/15.6\"/1366х768/4GB/500GB/Intel HD Graphics 505/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10 Home    NX.GFTER.040",
"71365217    Ноутбук PRESTIGIO SmartBook 116C Black     9 990    12 990    Intel Atom x5-Z8350 1.44GHz/11.6\"/1920x1080/2Gb/32Gb SSD/Intel HD Graphics 400/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10    PSB116C01BFH_BK_CIS",
"71372119    Ноутбук ACER Swift 3    47 990    49 000    Sparkly Silver (Intel Core I3-7100U 2400Mhz/14\"/1920х1080/4GB/256GB SSD/Intel HD Graphics 620/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win10    SF314-52-381G",
"71374824    Ноутбук LENOVO Yoga 520-14IKB    69 990    72 000    Intel Core i7 7500U 2700Mhz/14\"/1920х1080/8GB/1TB+128GB/nVidia GeForce 940MX/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win10    80X8001YRK",
"71375930    Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 330-14IGM    18 990    24 990    Intel Celeron N4000 1100Mhz/14\"/1366х768/4GB/500GB/Intel UHD Graphics 600/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win10 Home    81D0003CRU",
"71376799    Ноутбук HP 17-ab412ur    82 990    88 990    Intel Core i7-8750H 2.2GHz/17.3/1920х1080/12GB/1TB+128GB SSD/NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/DVD-RW/Wi-Fi/Bluetooth/Win 10 Homeх644JS50EA"]
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы когда я вводила наименование производителя (HP, LENOVO и т.д.) программа выводила все ноутбуки заданного производителя и их цены. 
Были попытки это реализовать, но код не работает.

```
for i in range(len(source_data)):
 a = source_data[i].split("    ")
 vend = (a[1].split(" ")[1])
 name = (a[1])
 price = (a[3])
  dict = {vend: name+price}
print(dict)
def get_price(vendor):
 print("Вы искали ноутбуки производителя {}".format(vendor))
 for vend in dict:
    if vend == vendor:
     print(dict.get(vendor))
def main():
 vendor = input()
get_price(vendor)
main()
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas

sep = (' ' * 4)
df = pandas.DataFrame([sd.split(sep) for sd in source_data])
df.columns = ['num', 'name_1', 'sum_1', 'sum_2', 'name_2', 'name_3', 'name_4', ]
df[df['name_1'].str.contains("LENOVO")]
```

out

```
         num                            name_1   sum_1   sum_2  \
1   71346124  Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 320-15ABR  34 800  36 990   
2   71366543         Ноутбук LENOVO 320-15IKBN  32 990  37 990   
5   71366549          Ноутбук LENOVO 320-15AST  26 990  29 990   
11  71374824     Ноутбук LENOVO Yoga 520-14IKB  69 990  72 000   
12  71375930  Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 330-14IGM  18 990  24 990   

                                               name_2      name_3      name_4  
1   Ноутбук LENOVO IdeaPad 320-15ABR(AMD A10-9620P...  80XS000MRK        None  
2   Intel Core I3-7100U 2400Mhz/15.6"/1920x1080/6G...  320-15IKBN  80XL003ARK  
5   AMD A9-9420 3000Mhz/15.6"/1366x768/8Gb/1Tb/AMD...   320-15AST  80XV00C9RK  
11  Intel Core i7 7500U 2700Mhz/14"/1920х1080/8GB/...  80X8001YRK        None  
12  Intel Celeron N4000 1100Mhz/14"/1366х768/4GB/5...  81D0003CRU        None
```